# .net SQL DateTime returning wrong value

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

If I use either

```
Select convert(datetime, Deldate, 113), Deldate
```

It returns datetime:

```
21/01/2015 23:00:00
```

Which is correct, its stored in the db table as datetime. 
But when inserting into a DB via datatable

```
(row.Item("Deldate").ToString())
```

it returns

```
22/01/2015 00:00:00
```

I also tried

```
 Dim DelDate As DateTime
 DelDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Item("crmp_deliverydate").ToString())
```

And it still returns `22/01/2015 00:00:00`

Can anyone help out, to get the actual datetime.
Thanks

Comment: Looks like the DB column might be Date only.  Try a time of 13:00 to make sure it isnt a timezone/UTC issue - if that comes back 0 as well, the column type may be wrong.

Comment: Yep your right. its stored in UTC, when I did one at 13:06 it came back as 14:06. so how do I retrieve and insert into my db as UTC?

Comment: Did you try row.Item("Deldate").ToUniversalTime